# How can I create my SQL code below to a loop so I do not need to write multiple lines of code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

```
table1
    id
    amount

table2
    id
    col1
    col2
    col3
    col4
    col5
```

And this SQL:

```
select 
    t2.col1/t1.amount as col1,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2)/t1.amount as col2,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3)/t1.amount as col3,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3 + t2.col4)/t1.amount as col4,
    (t2.col1 + t2.col2 + t2.col3 + t2.col4 + t2.col5)/t1.amount as col5
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

I want to create a loop for the above function so I do not need to write the select statement for 90 months. How can I do this?

example:

Current Table

```
Table 1         Table 2             
**Amount      1   2   3   4   5**
100        10  10  10  10  10
200         20  20  20  20  20
```

Expected Output

```
**1   2   3   4   5**
10% 20% 30% 40% 50%
10% 20% 30% 40% 50%
```

Comment: @Shrey . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: This isn't clear. Do you really have columns in `table2` all the way up to `col90`?

Comment: If you need to iterate a collection, it should be a collection of rows in sql.

Comment: What part of that query would change each iteration?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: This sounds as if you have a bad data model and the columns should in fact be rows.

Comment: Yes it had been better if columns were rown but the table is like this only and I want to take the cumulative sum of columns in terms of percentage of the amount in another field I have added the tables sample for clarification. of the columns

Comment: maybe you can unpivot the results to be able to sum more easily? https://codingsight.com/understanding-pivot-unpivot-and-reverse-pivot-statements/

Answer (score 1):

If you're really stuck with this **broken** table layout for 90 columns, your only option is manually writing out the long version of this expression:

```
coaelsce(col1,0) + coalesce(col2, 0) + ... + coalesce(col90,0)
```

Using bulk columns like this is not good database design, and hence the database doesn't support it with any easy syntax that would let your write anything shorter.

The one thing you maybe can do is create a **View** to mimic better table design, but the code for that is still gonna be pretty ugly and *SLOW* (though an indexed/materialized view might speed it up).

To accomplish this you have to start with a `numbers` table containing values for 1 through 90:

```
CREATE View BetterTable2 
As
SELECT t2.id, n.number As ColNumber
    CASE n.number
         WHEN 1 THEN t2.col1
         WHEN 2 THEN t2.col2
         WHEN 3 THEN t2.col3
         -- ...
         WHEN 90 THEN t2.col90
         ELSE NULL END As ColValue
FROM numbers n
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON n.number >= 1 and n.number <= 90
```

You can also see we still need list out all the columns by hand, but if you really need a running total, it will at least make that possible from here so you only have to write out each of those columns *once*.

Now you can further write a query like this:

```
SELECT t2_0.id, t2_0.ColNumber,
    SUM(t2_1.ColValue)/t1.amount As Percent
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN BetterTable2 t2_0 ON t2_0.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN BetterTable2 t2_1 ON t2_1.id = t2_0.id AND t2_1.ColNumber <= t2_0.ColNumber
GROUP BY t2_0.id, t2_0.ColNumber, t1.amount
```

And from here you can do a `PIVOT` if you really need it, which is usually best handled in your client code or reporting tool.